OpenAPI, yaml and enumAsRef: true
How to prevent OpenAPI generate enum value from .yaml file?
This is what it generates:
public enum DocumentCode {
  INSURANCE("INSURANCE"),
  ELECTRICITY_BILL("ELECTRICITY_BILL"),

And this is what I want:
INSURANCE,
ELECTRICITY_BILL

My .yaml:
DocumentCode:
  type: string
  enum:
  - INSURANCE
  - ELECTRICITY_BILL
  - DRIVER_LICENSE
  - VEHICLE_REGISTRATION_CERTIFICATE
  - SYSTEM- CUSTOM

The issue is that I want the enum fields to not have values so that Spring Boot can automatically store them as 1, 2, 3, 4 in the database and then convert them back to enum strings when retrieving them.
I tried enumAsRef: true but dont know how to use it.

"Spring Boot can automatically store them as 1, 2, 3, 4" and it doesn't now?

If you want to store integers in DB you need to add @Enumerated to fields.
